# AWS - cannot access S3 bucket via HTTPS endpoint due to location constraint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The following services are activated:

1. a `S3` bucket in `ap-east-1` where my static web pages are saved,
2. a domain name registered on `Route 53`,
3. a SSL certificate requested via `Certification Manager` at `us-east-1`,
4. a `CloudFront` distribution for enabling HTTPS access to my web pages.

It is stated in this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html) that a single SSL certificate should suffice if `CloudFront` is used.

When I navigate to my URL `https://www.example.com` in Chrome, the following error is returned.

[image: error_msg]

How to make my pages **globally accessible via HTTPS**?

---

**Update**

It seems that the behavior of `S3` buckets in `ap-east-1` is different from the buckets located in other regions as stated in [my follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945849/aws-invalidaccesskeyid-returned-when-accessing-s3-bucket-via-cloudfront-https).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that the URL provided for S3 included the wrong (or no) region.

You should use the format:

```
bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com
```

You are probably missing the region.

See: [Using Amazon S3 Origins, MediaPackage Channels, and Custom Origins for Web Distributions - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html)

Comment: Interesting.  Specifying the region is a good idea, but CloudFront historically has not required that the regional endpoint be specified, and it would find the bucket with just `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` beginning within a couple of hours after bucket creation, worst case.  It looks like something has changed in S3 and as of now this condition -- and this specific exception applying to "get object" request -- is specific to buckets in `ap-east-1` -- which is, as of now, the newest AWS region to come online.

Comment: Further research confirms that buckets in the ap-east-1 region do indeed exhibit entirely different behavior than buckets in other regions, behind CloudFront.  The page you linked to does call this out in somewhat general terms, discouraging use of the global endpoint: *Another option might be to use the following more general format, but be aware that this format doesn't work for Regions launched in 2019 or later: `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com`*

Comment: This issue occurs with any _opt-in_ AWS regions, including ap-east-1, me-south-1, and other new regions. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html