# AWS - InvalidAccessKeyId returned when accessing S3 bucket via CloudFront HTTPS distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921260/aws-cannot-access-s3-bucket-via-https-endpoint-due-to-location-constraint) on the same case.

After solving my previous issue, my AWS is set up with the following services.

1. `S3` bucket in `ap-east-1` without static website hosting.
2. `CloudFront` HTTPS distribution with a SSL certificate requested from `ACM` in `us-east-1`.
3. Alias pointing to the `CloudFront` distribution in `Route 53`.

[image: InvalidAccessKeyId screenshot]

When I try navigating to the distribution endpoint using the alias configured in `Route 53`, it always returns `InvalidAccessKeyId` error, and saying that the access key does not exist. The key is always the same for every requests, and is prefixed with `AKIA`.

I have looked into my `IAM` console, no users have been created. There are only 2 roles which I believe was auto-created by AWS.

By the way, even if I disable auto-updating `S3` bucket policy when creating new `CloudFront` distribution, my bucket policy will be modified automatically, where the `Principal` field is set to `"AWS": "ADIA..."`. I have tried replacing it with `"CanonicalUser": "<my OAI that the CloudFront distribution is using>"`, but it will be reverted to `"AWS": "ADIA..."` several minutes later.

Does anyone know how to tackle this invalid access key error?

---

**Update**

I have created another `S3` bucket in `ap-southeast-1` and carried out the exact same steps by allowing `CloudFront` generates bucket policy automatically, then configured alias settings in `Route 53` console.

Below is the auto-generated bucket policy.

[image: S3 auto-generated bucket policy]

Then, I copy and paste that policy to my original `ap-east-1` bucket, the only difference is in the line `"AWS": "..."`, but it doesn't allow me to save it, stating that there is error in the principal.

[image: S3 bucket policy error with principal]

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot here ? InvalidAccessKeyId shouldn't coming using CloudFront.

Comment: Problem with uploading screenshot from my phone. I will upload one after work tonight.

Comment: Keep the bucket policy update from CloudFront when you use OAI, this makes sure that CloudFront has the correct Principle on bucket policy, OAI creates bucket policy, it doesn't add bucket ACL.

Comment: @JamesDean Screenshot uploaded.

Comment: @S.C. I was able to duplicate this behavior using a CloudFront distribution and a bucket in the ap-east-1 region.  I was also able to confirm that AWS engineers are aware of the issue, so a fix should be forthcoming.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with CloudFront and [opt-in AWS regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html). Unfortunately the workaround is to set your bucket policy to allow public access (something like `"Principal": "*"` in the bucket policy), or just use a different region for now.

You can also try complaining to AWS support. Customer impact tends to get aws bugs resolved more quickly...